# Variable is overwritten in if statement

Tags: python

Write a program to read 3 integers from the user, and calculate the sum of the integers. However, if one of the values is the same as another of the values, it should not count towards the sum.

```
Enter a: 3
Enter b: 3
Enter c: 3
The sum is 3
```

The correct answer should be 0, however I realise by my first if statement a has been reassigned to 0 and since by that point a!=c for 0!=3, I am stuck on this testcase

```
a = int(input("Enter a: "))
b = int(input("Enter b: "))
c = int(input("Enter c: "))

if a == b:
    a = 0
    b = 0
elif a == c:
        a = 0
        c = 0
elif b == c:
        b = 0
        c = 0
print("The sum is", a + b + c)
```

Comment: Add additional condition: if a == b and b == c, then sum is 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and only count the values that appear once:

```
count = Counter((a, b, c))

s = sum(value for value, quantity in count.items() if quantity == 1)
print(f"The sum is {s}")
```

---

the problem with your implementation is that `if a == b` the other two `elif`s will never be executed. you need change the `elif`s to `if`s.

then you would test `a == c` again (after having set `a` to `0`). for that approach to work you would have to use temporary variables instead:

```
tmp_a, tmp_b, tmp_c = a, b, c

if a == b:
    tmp_a, tmp_b = 0, 0
if a == c:
    tmp_a, tmp_c = 0, 0
if b == c:
    tmp_b, tmp_c = 0, 0

print(f"The sum is {tmp_a + tmp_b + tmp_c}")
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you reassign 0 to values that could be duplicate of other values. You first need to do the comparison between all values at the same time, and then do single comparison.

```
a = int(input("Enter a: "))
b = int(input("Enter b: "))
c = int(input("Enter c: "))

s = 0

if a == b and a == c:
    s = 0
elif a == b:
    s = c
elif a == c:
    s = b
elif b == c:
    s = a
else:
    s = a + b + c

print("The sum is ", s)
```

Comment: @hiroprotagonist good point here, thank you, I edit my answer